# Accessing Internet through Android Application

Tags: android, wcf, http, connection

We, two team mates and I, are trying to access a WCF web service through an Android application. We are using a JSON for the transport of objects. We have tested that the service can be called through HTTP via google chrome, internet explorer and the android browser on the emulator.

We have already set up the internet permission in the android manifest using

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

We are using the HttpClient and the HttpResponse objects, to connect to the WCF Server.

Currently we are attempting to access the server both locally on the machine that the emulator is being run on, and one that has been hosted on the local network.

Our problem seems to be that we cannot connect to any server through our app, whether it is our server we are trying to connect to, or any other server.

We have already tested the server connection with a windows phone program using http, which seems to work fine.

Are we missing something obvious? We really do feel like we are banging our heads on a brick wall.

Many thanks for any advice given and if any more information is needed please feel free to reply.

Comment: you should post the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `10.0.2.2` as IP for the server running on the same machine as the android Emulator...

Comment: We have tried with both localhost, 10.0.2.2, and the web address of the server hosted on the network. Neither gives results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Traceview http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html to find out where the problem is happening. You can use it to create a trace file showing the status of the network connection and where it is failing.